# How to find, read and display a line from a text file with Java

Tags: java, file

I have a text file entailing fake airplane records. I need to write a code that will find a record based on its ID String and display it. I have a main, class, and text file. Basically the user should be able to enter the "ID" say 'DA0' and the code will find it, and display the line.

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package lastassignment;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author djiml
 */
public class LastAssignment {
    
    public LastAssignment() {
        
    }
    
    private ArrayList<AirplaneSeatRecords> airplaneSeats = new ArrayList<AirplaneSeatRecords>();
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String airlineIndex;
        String name;
        int seat;
        double ticketCost;

    public void OpenRecord() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream inputfile = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(inputfile);
        
        while (inFile.hasNext()) {
            airlineIndex = inFile.next();
            ticketCost = inFile.nextDouble();
            seat = inFile.nextInt();
            name = inFile.nextLine();
            airplaneSeats.add(new AirplaneSeatRecords(airlineIndex, ticketCost, seat, name));
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input;
        
        
        System.out.println("What would you like to do?:");
        System.out.println("1. Open a Record.");
        System.out.println("2. Display a Record.");
        System.out.println("3. Display All Records.");
        System.out.println("4. Add a New Record.");
        System.out.println("5. Edit a Record.");
        System.out.println("6. Delete a Record.");
        System.out.println("7. Save Progress.");
        System.out.println("8. Exit.");
        System.out.print(": ");
        
        input = scnr.nextInt();
        
        if (input != 8) {
            
            switch(input) {
            
            case 1 ->  new LastAssignment().OpenRecord();
            
            case 2 -> System.out.println("FIXME: Add 'Display a Record'");
            
            case 3 -> System.out.println("FIXME: Add 'Display All Records'");
            
            case 4 -> System.out.println("FIXME: Add 'Add a New Record'");
            
            case 5 -> System.out.println("FIXME: Add 'Edit a Record'");
            
            case 6 -> System.out.println("FIXME: Add 'Delete a Record'");
            
            case 7 -> System.out.println("FIXME: Add 'Save Progress'");
        
        }
            
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("FIXME: Add 'Exit'");
        }
    }
    
}
```

Class File

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package lastassignment;

/**
 *
 * @author djiml
 */
public class AirplaneSeatRecords {
    private String airlineIndex;
    private double ticketCost;
    private String customerFlying;
    private int seatNum;
    
    public AirplaneSeatRecords() {
        // Constructor
    }
    
    public AirplaneSeatRecords(String ID, double cost, int seat, String name) {
        airlineIndex = ID;
        ticketCost = cost;
        seatNum = seat;
        customerFlying = name;
    }
    
    public void displayTickets() {
        System.out.printf("%8s \t %-20s \t\t $%.2f \t %d \n", airlineIndex, customerFlying, ticketCost, seatNum);
    }
    
    public String getTicketID() {
        return airlineIndex;
    }
    
    public double getTicketCost() {
        return ticketCost;
    }
    
    public int getSeatNum() {
        return seatNum;
    }
    
    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerFlying;
    }
    
    public void setSeatNum(int seat) {
        seatNum = seat;
    }
    
    public void setCustomerName(String name) {
        customerFlying = name;
    }
    
    public void setTicketPrice(double price) {
        ticketCost = price;
    }
    
    
}
```

Text File

```
DA0 215.00 19 Doug Anderson
DA1 200.00 20 Drew Bates
DA2 185.00 21 Theresa Patty
DA3 170.00 22 Andrew Abrams
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `case 2` ask the user again for an ID and read it with Scanner.

Create a method where you iterate in a loop through your `airplaneSeats` array, and if the entered ID matches the ID of one of the `AirplaneSeatRecords` in your array, then print the record and break the loop. You already have the necessary methods for it in the `AirplaneSeatRecords` class.

Also, don't forget to add a default case to your switch statement.

Comment: That's a [`switch` expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/language/switch-expressions.html), it doesn't need `break`s.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thank you for your comment! I learned something new :) I am only familiar with Java 8, that is why I wasn't aware of the new features and syntax for the `switch` statement in later versions. I edited my answer accordingly. The `default` case is still relevant though?

Comment: Yes, the switch expression needs to be exhaustive so in this case `default` is needed.

Comment: What do you mean by iterate in a loop? And which method from Airplane Seat records?

Comment: @EggShweg if you have a list of objects and you need to pick one based on some criteria (like ID), then you need to go (iterate) through each of those in a loop (or a stream) in order to find it. Are you familiar with loops or streams? Since you have things like a switch statement or file streaming in your code, I've assumed you were. Or is it some predefined code with missing parts and you are searching for a ready solution?

Comment: Streams are new to me. My prof gave us the stream code and suggested we use a switch for this assignment.

Comment: @YuliyaSheludyakova I used a for-each loop instead, but thank you! Your comment helped me greatly!

Comment: @EggShweg that was the right loop choice ;-)

Comment: @EggShweg you might also upvote or accept my answer, that would also help me in collecting some reputation points :)